# Energy consumption based on temperature - what models?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I need to predict future 1 or 2 days energy consumption based on previous data:
I have data related to daily energy consumption and various HOURLY data related to temperature (temperature, relative temperature, wind speed, dew point, atmospheric pressure).

In SPSS or Excel or R, what analysis should I make? Could you, please, mention the needed steps (an algorithm).

Is ARIMA required or a linear regression (or other kind?) is enough?

Thank you,
Catalin

Comment: Weather data is available from several public sites that goes back to the 19th c. In your case, you should have *at least* two or three years of daily information to adequately initialize a model with the many seasonal factors that would be useful in conditioning the parameters of a model and forecast the next few days of consumption.

Comment: I have weather data for 3 years (365 * 3) and 48 * 4 data column sets with data for temperature, relative temp, dew point and atmospheric pressure). What models should I use for prediction?

Comment: Just gave a response here to a similar query ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271745/finding-an-appropriate-trend-test/271802#271802

Comment: Voting to leave open: Despite the mention of software, this seems focused on model choice.